# Can't get second sound to load in streaming .mp3 player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, mp3

I'm struggling with a flash file that I want to play two different sound files when the appropriate buttons are pressed.
I've gotten it to the point where it will load without any errors popping up, but instead of playing the second sound when I press the button for that sound, it plays the first sound again. 
Here's the code:

```
var sc1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var s1:Sound = new Sound();
s1.load(new URLRequest("http://www.website.com/wells.mp3"));

wellsplay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSound);
wellsstop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopSound);

function playSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
sc1 = s1.play();
}
function stopSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
sc1.stop();
}

var sc2:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var s2:Sound = new Sound();
s2.load(new URLRequest("http://www.website.com/waves.mp3"));

wavesplay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSound);
wavesstop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopSound);

function playSound2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
sc2 = s2.play();
}
function stopSound2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
sc2.stop();
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 wavesplay_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSound2);
 wavesstop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopSound2);
```

Comment: Gee, I hope I do eventually cotton to such basic stuff. Thanks. That made it work. I think I'm at the stage where code is still a wilderness to me, so I end up wandering in circles. But I'm working my way through tutorials

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.